# Gzip xml before sending to JMeter

Tags: xml, jmeter, gzip

I have a server which accepts JSON format. I have successfully embedded XML in JSON .
But now I need to send this XML in Gzip format.
Is there any way to do this in JMeter?

```
{
  "MessageId": "null:,
  "Data": "Here is the xml message",
  "SourceMessageIdentifier": "String"
}
```

I mean I need to just gzip the Data, not the whole request.
Is there any way to do that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33718462/how-to-post-gzip-request-with-apache-jmeter.. This covers part of it. I am not sure it will compressed whole request or just xml.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38035670/how-to-use-java-program-in-bean-pre-processor. Solved.